# Convert [object HTMLDocument] Into a String

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating an HTML document object:

```js
let newHTMLDocument = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();

let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </body>
</html>`;

newHTMLDocument.open();
newHTMLDocument.write( html );
newHTMLDocument.close();

console.log( String(newHTMLDocument) ); // [object HTMLDocument]
```

Instead of "[object HTMLDocument]," how can I convert newHTMLDocument into a string containing all of the HTML code, including the doctype and html tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this one `console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newHTMLDocument))`
it will grab html content from document into string format

## demo

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hijahevepe/1/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: This doesn't work. It doesn't return the doctype, which I need in order to be a full representation of the original HTML document code.

Comment: @GTSJoe try this `console.log( newHTMLDocument.documentElement.outerHTML );`

Comment: @uzauf I need the <doctype> too.

Comment: try this one `console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newHTMLDocument))`

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you, Uzaif! Please update your answer to include console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newHTMLDocument)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `console.log(newHTMLDocument.documentElement);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerhtml property of the element.do this thing.

`ele = newHTMLDocument.getElementByTagName('html')
console.log(ele[0].innerHTML);`